# 100 of subviews need to be added on run time in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to add dynamic subviews on the basis of data returned from **web-service**. some time i need to ***add 100 of subviews*** inside the cell which has a horizontal scrolling. My tableview getting stuck while scrolling (because of loading the 100 of views). what is the better way to add these subviews inside `tableviewcell`

Comment: Why not add a horizontal collection view to your table view cell and then you could dequeue them and not have to add 100 subviews at once.

Comment: that would be a good option. let me try. Thanks

Comment: If all your subviews are of the same class then this is the optimal solution.

Comment: If you add 100 subView on single UITableView it stuck in scrolling, because Cell is not made for this. here you can use that much of UITableViewCell so those will deque. 
If you want to add in cell only then try CollectionView inside the cell but it again take time load or scrolling stuck problem will come.
There another way which is easy for development as stack view but it more stuck while scrolling.

Comment: Getting stuck in either way :(